# Maintain low profile - Help overcome complexity

Tags: motivation, teamwork

I have a problem at my work place and I feel it's my inferiority complex. I was given a task to be completed to which I am kind of new.So It took me more time and I was partially able to complete it. But then my senior took control over my work and started working on that task.He was able to complete it within two days and he showed the demo as well.I feel bad and I worry what my manager or team leader would think about me.
How ever the Senior guy himself motivated me saying everybody undergoes such phase in their career and motivated me to be upbeat. I feel bad and I don't know how to react myself. How should I overcome this complexity?

Thank you!

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2696) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for the suggestion. this is a real situation that I experienced and I feel my problem can be best expressed through this. I don't know to generalize my situation.

Comment: This is going to get shut down.  Look at what the sr did and learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How ever the Senior guy himself motivated me saying everybody
>   undergoes such phase in their career and motivated me to be upbeat.

I think this is the bottom line. Your manager is happy when he/she see's that you are *moving in the right direction*

They know that you're relatively new, that you have a lot to learn, that you may not have confidence.

They want to see results, true; however, they do recognize effort and a willingness. You must give an aura of eagerness and readiness.

Confidence, generally, comes with experience. Experience happens with time and efforts (moreso if you add both strong efforts, plus time), as you learn from you mistakes and gain solid skills.

One last point - if you see that you're deficient in the social skills arena, then you should try to go outside your comfort zone a little. Maybe try attending speech groups (like Toastmasters), or just making efforts to participate in activities/events/volunteering more.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this. I am trying to overcome my sensitiveness and trying to focus to them maximum. But my all time feeling of "what they will think about me" is bothering me highly.

Comment: @ANSHAA - Best of luck to you : - )

Comment: Also I always get lot of questions. In a team particularly smaller one, is it good or bad to ask for too many questions(sensibly, not idiotic ones)?

Comment: @ANSHAA - it's *great* to ask question, please keep asking questions! Never feel shy to learn.  Some quote I read once "There is no shame in not knowing; the shame lies in not finding out." ( Russian Proverb  )

Comment: In my experience, those who ask a lot (even too much) do better than those who ask too little, all else equal

Comment: @ANSHAA Don't just ask a question every time you don't know something though, and make sure you ask the right questions. Don't ask for the answer, ask how to find the answer. And put in a good faith effort to find it yourself first. That's not to discourage you from asking questions, but helping ensure you ask good questions.

Comment: @ptfreak Thanks!I will definitely take your suggestion.